# How can I loop a scrapy script?

Tags: python, scrapy

Scenario: I have a scrapy script which scrapes the site. Once the required keyword is found in the scraped detail, it'll send a mail. There is a site which changes data every 30 minutes, I need to scrape again after the specific keyword and send the email if found. How can I loop every 30 minutes in scrapy Python?

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import time

class NewFilmSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'new_film_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.xxx.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.xxx.in/xxx/now-showing']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        t = threading.Thread(self.getDetails(response))
        t.start()

    def getDetails(self, response):
        FROM_ADDRESS = 'xxx@gmail.com'
        PASSWORD = 'xxx'
        TO_ADDRESS= 'xxx@gmail.com'
        HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
        PORT=587
        records = response.xpath('//section[@class="main-section"]/section[2]/section[@class="movie__listing now-showing"]/ul/li/div/dl/dt/a/text()').extract()
        if 'KEYWORD' in str(records):
            receivers = [TO_ADDRESS]
            msg="Booking Opened"
            try:
                smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(HOST,PORT)
                smtpObj.set_debuglevel(1)
                smtpObj.ehlo()
                smtpObj.starttls()
                smtpObj.login(FROM_ADDRESS,PASSWORD)
                smtpObj.sendmail(FROM_ADDRESS, receivers, msg)   
                smtpObj.quit()      
                print "Successfully sent email"
            except Exception as e:
                print "Error: unable to send email"
         time.sleep(60) #checking for every minute
```

This code runs the script and sends the mail, but I don't know how to loop it.

Comment: Maybe to try to solve it with cron tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spawn a thread that runs every 30 min like so:

```
import threading

def __init__(self):
    . . .    
    t = threading.Thread(self.every_thirty_min())
    t.start()

def every_thirty_min(self):
    while True:
        print('up')
        // do stuff
        time.sleep(1800) // 30 min
```